# Write date and variable to file

Tags: python-3.x, date, variables, logging

I am trying to write a variable and the date and time on the same line to a file, which will simulate a log file.

Example: `July 25 2018 6:00 pm - Variable contents here`

So far I am able to write the variable to the file but I am unsure how to use the datetime library or other similar libraries. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Below is the current script.

```
import subprocess
import datetime
var = "test"

with open('auditlog.txt', 'a') as logfile:
    logfile.write(var + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way I found is doing something like this:

```
import time

var = time.asctime()
print(var)
```

Result: Thu Jul 26 00:46:04 2018

If you want to change the placements of y/m/d etc. you can alternatively use this:

```
import time

var = time.strftime("%B %d %Y %H:%M pm", time.localtime())
print(var)
```

Result: July 26 2018 00:50 pm

Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

By the way, is the subprocess intended in your code? You don't need it to open/write to files. Also you should do `logfile.close()` in your code after you wrote to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using timevar = datetime.now() and it resulted in: 2018-07-25 22:56:36.098896test - this was a bit difficult to read. The method you showed me looks way better. Thanks for your help. Subprocess is used in another section of the code. I attempted using subprocess for this but I found it a bit more difficult to implement and I didn't like the results.